# Loops | list | extraction

Tags: python, list, loops, file, text-extraction

I'm trying to import some elements from file, do some work with them and print [extract to file in the future] results in a list. As Im breaking the code peace by peace, Im getting all information that I need, but when Im trying to extract all info at once with a loop I get this:

```
spotify:track:0PJ4RVL5wCeHDO8wHpk3YG
t
0 K S s
1 n t p
2 a e o
3 s v t
```

Loop breaks the word [last element of the list] by letter

I'm using several loops, there are some ids that I don't know how to attach needed info to these ids

```
import spotipy
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter
import xlrd
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials

path = "C:\\Users\\Karolis\\Desktop\\Python\\Failai\\Gabalai.xlsx"
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(path)
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
sheet2 = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
sheet.cell_value(0, 0)
sheet2.cell_value(0, 0)
client_id = ''
client_secret = ''

for ix in range(sheet.nrows):
    title = (sheet.cell_value(ix, 0))
    artist = (sheet2.cell_value(ix, 1))

# cia apacioj istraukia gabalo uri
client_credentials_manager = SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret)
sp = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=client_credentials_manager)
sp.trace = False
search_query = title + ' ' + artist
result = sp.search(search_query)
for i in result['tracks']['items']:
    # Find a songh that matches title and artist
    if (i['artists'][0]['name'] == artist) and (i['name'] == title):
        uri = (i['uri'])
        break
else:
    try:
        # Just take the first song returned by the search (might be named differently)
        print(result['tracks']['items'][0]['uri'])
    except:
        # No results for artist and title
        print("Cannot Find URI")

# cia apacioj istraukia gabalo info pagal jo uri
uri = (i['uri'])

client_credentials_manager = SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret)
sp = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=client_credentials_manager)
sp.trace = False
features = sp.audio_features(uri)

for p in range(len(title)):
    print(p, artist[p], title[p],uri[p])

book1.close()
```

I'm a beginner at programming and I'm totally lost at this point.

Thank you for any help provided

Comment: What exactly is your problem? What did you expect to get instead of what you're getting?

Comment: My desirable outcome would be:
` artis1| title1| uri1
  artis2| title2| uri2
  artis3| title3| uri3 ` etc
in that order

Answer (score 0):

Your last loop,

```
for p in range(len(title)):
    print(p, artist[p], title[p],uri[p])
```

is explicitly printing each character of the artist, title, and uri. I think you mean to be looping over a list of titles, and indexing into lists of artists, titles, and uris, but instead you are looping over the length of a string and indexing into strings.